# Gradle doesn't find .aar file on Maven repo on Bintray

Tags: android, maven, gradle, aar, bintray

... even when the error reports the correct download URL.

(Bintray details below.)

**Gradle Repo**

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/myUsername/myRepo/' }
}
```

**Dependencies**

```
compile('com.domain.groupid:library-core:v1.2.3@aar') {
    transitive=true
}
compile('com.domain.groupid:library-support:v1.2.3@aar') {
    transitive=true
}
```

**Error**

```
Error:Could not find library-core.aar (com.domain.groupid:library-core:v1.2.3).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://dl.bintray.com/myUsername/myRepo/com/domain/groupid/library-core/v1.2.3/library-core-v1.2.3.aar
```

If I copy that URL, I can download it in a signed out window. Why does Gradle have a problem with it?

There is another similar compile dependency (listed here as `library-support`), but I'm assuming it didn't get to it because this one failed first.

**The setup...**

I have a personal public repo on Bintray, with two android libraries.

```
https://bintray.com/myUsername/myRepo/library-core
https://bintray.com/myUsername/myRepo/library-support
```

Both have versions upload by the bintray rule in my library's gradle scripts. The versions upload, I can see them in the bintray UI, and I can download them and see that they are what I expected:

```
https://dl.bintray.com/myUsername/myRepo/com/domain/groupid/library-core/maven-metadata.xml
https://dl.bintray.com/myUsername/myRepo/com/domain/groupid/library-core/library-core-v1.2.3/library-core-v1.2.3-sources.jar
https://dl.bintray.com/myUsername/myRepo/com/domain/groupid/library-core/library-core-v1.2.3/library-core-v1.2.3.aar
https://dl.bintray.com/myUsername/myRepo/com/domain/groupid/library-core/library-core-v1.2.3/library-core-v1.2.3.pom
// Same for library-support. All of these download in a signed out window.
```

Is gradle expecting something else?

Comment: Can you please provide the _actual_ link to your dependencies on Bintray? I'd like reproduce the issue. BTW: It's very uncommon to use a `v` prefix for the version of libraries in Maven. It's implied that this attribute _is_ the version. Maybe that has something to do with your problem.

Comment: You are the winner.  I re-uploaded without the v in the version name, and updated my dependencies to match, and life is good. Please post your comment as an answer so I can award you some reputation.

Comment: Great! Please find the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maven usually doesn't expect the `v` prefix in the version attribute. It's implied by the order of coordinate syntax: `<group>:<name>:<version>`. Using semantic versioning for the version number should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, adding another answer to hopefully help others in the future.

In my case, I first only uploaded the .jar file to the maven repo, then when I uploaded the .aar file, it couldn't find it even though the error URL properly linked to the artifact.

Adding

```
--refresh-dependencies
```

to my gradle command fixed the issue for me